# Meaning of exit status 1 returned by linux command

Tags: linux, command, exitstatus

What is meaning of exit status 1 returned by linux command? Like 127 exit status indicates "command not found".

I have visited http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/exitcodes.html page, does it mean exit status 1 does not have particular special meaning?

Comment: The ABS link is confused. These exit codes are not "reserved" and the table is a happy drunk mixture of Bash-internal usage, general Unix conventions, and the author's loud opinion.

Comment: See also now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530696/linux-how-to-get-error-description-by-error-number/36566055#36566055

Answer (score 46):

The only general convention is that a zero exit status signifies success, whereas any non-zero exit status is a failure.
Different non-zero values may indicate the reason for the exit status, usually documented for the particular program.

C's `<stdlib.h>` include file defines two constants:

1. `EXIT_FAILURE` (1)
2. `EXIT_SUCCESS` (0)

"man-pages(7)" suggests to document the meaning of the exit status in section **EXIT STATUS**.

Many -- but certainly not all -- command-line tools return exit code 1 for syntax error, i.e. you had too few arguments or an invalid option.

Many -- but, alas, not all -- command-line tools have a [manual page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page). By convention, it should document the exit codes of the program, but many do not.

Answer (score 18):

You can see the value of the exit status using `man`.

Giving an example below:

```
man ls
```

Now search for string **exit**

Adding screen shot below:

[image]

Comment: As tripleee posted not all command's man page documented exit codes. I am facing exit status related problem for command msgfmt, it's man page does not documented about exit codes.

Comment: [msgfmt.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gettext.git/tree/gettext-tools/src/msgfmt.c) seems to use the generic [EXIT_FAILURE](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html) in basically every error situation. There would be an error message telling you what went wrong, though.

Answer (score 0):

Exit Code 1 means that a container terminated, typically due to an application error or an invalid reference. A non-zero (1-255) exit status indicates failure.

For example, if a Java library is running , and the library throws a compiler error, the container might terminate with Exit Code 1.

A command which exits with a zero (0) exit status means it succeeded.