# What happens if a variable is assigned with command expression in backticks

Tags: linux, bash

Below is the code of bash:

```
a=`echo hello`
echo $a
```

output is :

> hello

But I think it should be:

> hello
>   0

Comment: the exitcode does not displayed you can do `echo $?` to print exitcode of last command

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to make key works of code highlight on SO?

Comment: Could you please retitle this?  It looks like you are asking what `$?` means (which of course is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530696/linux-how-to-get-error-description-by-error-number/36566055#36566055) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530696/linux-how-to-get-error-description-by-error-number/36566055#36566055)) but this seems to be about an incorrect assumption about the result of command substitution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You *mistakenly* think** that `` a=`echo hello` ``:

- executes `echo hello` and prints its stdout output *directly to the caller's stdout*,
- and then assigns the *exit code* (return value) of the `echo` command to variable `$a`.

**Neither is true; instead:**

- `echo hello`'s stdout output is *captured in memory* (without printing to the caller's stdout; that's how [command substitutions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution) work),
- and *that captured output* is assigned to `$a`.

**A command's exit code (a return value indicating success vs. failure) is *never directly returned*** in POSIX-like shells such as Bash.
The only way to use an exit code is either:

- explicitly, by accessing special variable `$?` *immediately* after the command (`$?` contains the *most recent* command's exit code)
- implicitly, in conditionals (a command whose exit code is `0` evaluates to *true* in a conditional, any other exit code implies *false*).

Thus, to achieve what you're really trying to do, use:

```
echo 'hello'  # Execute a command directly (its stdout output goes to the caller's stdout)
a=$?          # Save the previous command's exit code in var. $a
echo "$a"     # Echo the saved exit code.
```

Answer (score 6):

You think wrong ;-)

Putting the command in backticks assigns the output (stdout) from the expression on the right to the variable on the left.

`$?` gives you the "output status" (or return code) of the command - aka the "0" you were expecting.

So:

```
a=`echo hello`
```

Runs the command "echo hello" but instead of echoing to stdout, it "echoes" to varaiable `a`. So a=whatever_the_command_would_have_written_to_stdout (in this case "hello") - nothing is actually written to stdout because it is "captured" by the ``s

Comment: So what's the meaning and effect of `echo $a` in my sample code?

Comment: `a=\`echo hello\``  translates to set variable a to the standard output of running the command `echo hello` or as you've seen when you did it: `a=hello`

Comment: Indeed, I don't understand. Does the value of `a`  is NULL? If it equals `a=hello`, then it would outputs two hello. That is : hello<br/>hello

Comment: Your question includes proof that `$a` ends up with the value "hello" - Why are you now thinking it is NULL?

Comment: `echo hello` means excutes command echo hello? And then `echo $a`, it would output hello twice.

Comment: I've explained it. You have seen the results. You seem to be trying to make it more complicated than it is...

Comment: @hel Though you should properly quote the result; `echo "$hello"`.

Answer (score -1):

As this [[ this ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38603251/1620779) answer already mentioned, the return value for the last executed command is stored in

```
$? # ${?} is sometimes needed
```

If you wish `a` to contain 'hello' and the return value of `echo hello` in separate lines, ie

```
hello
0
```

below is one way to do it

```
$ a=`echo -en "hello\n" && echo -n $?` # here $? is ret val for 1st echo
$ echo -e "$a"
hello
0
```

**Note**

- `-n` with `echo` suppresses the trailing new line
- `-e` with `echo` interprets escape sequences
- Since `&&` is the logical and operator, the second `echo` wouldn't have been executed had the first `echo` failed
- Another important point to note is that even the assignment ie

  ```
  a=b
  ```

  has a return value.

Comment: To the downvoter, I understood the first answer was crap. But I have rectified the issue with the edit. You may consider retracting the downvote.

Comment: From the comments to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38603247/6379160) answer, it's clear that the op doesn't follow simple explanation. Also this doesn't t answer the question.