# What does "Process finished with exit code 1" mean in intellij-idea?

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I got the error "Process finished with exit code 1" when I was running my Java code. I am using Intellij IDEA 2018.3. Below is the error log I got.

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: Zero is the exit code indicating success, whereas any non-zero exit code indicates that something went wrong, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965762/. In your case it looks like the program stopped due to an uncaught exception.

Comment: Are you very sure this is JavaScript not Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While running a Java application in Intellij Idea, after the program execution, JVM prints the exit code to the console. If the program terminates without any exception, exit code 0 is printed. Otherwise, any signed integer may be outputted.

Answer (score 5):

To get more information on the exit code try putting a try catch around the SpringApplication.run() function like this:

```
try
{
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
catch (Throwable throwable)
{
    System.out.println(throwable.toString());
    throwable.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Your answer really helped me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For springboot projects, the most common reason is `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException`.
Search `BeanCreationException`, debug at each construct function, and debug the projects.
Then you will find out the 'beanName' with problem, then you can focus on the bean.

for example:

[image]